# Using a 4Tb Maxell e-series external HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

Here is Patrick from France and a faithful Ubuntu user.
I just bought a 4tb external HDD from Maxwell to make a NAS connecting it to a wintel pro box running ubuntu mate.
I tested it on many Ubuntu (and one windows 7) computers. I hardly see only one partition of 160gb. I tried to modify it with all tools available (gparted, gfdisk, ...). I have never been able to recover the missing 3.840Gb.

I don't know what to do now. I am sure that the disk is really a 4tb (it is all new) but I am not sure the firmware in the box would prevent Ubuntu to see the whole size.
Now I have 3 solutions:

1. There is a way to make it work with your help
2. I can open the box to get the disk out, install it in a new more versatile box.
3. Resell the HDD

HELP please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Gparted and create a new GPT partition table (menu "Device").

Then you will be able to create partitions larger than 1TB.